# Elasticsearch filtering results from a MySQL JDBC river

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, jdbc, elasticsearch, tire

Using Tire in my Rails Application to communicate with Elasticsearch. So far, things are working fine.

The problem is indexing some external data sources.

I have additional sources that aren't updated within Rails and am using the [Elasticsearch river JDBC plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) to poll the database every 60s to get this info.

This data is accessed within the Rails application. In other models I have used a simple filter to restrict a user's access to the search data:

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 50) do |s|
    ...
    filter << { :terms => { location_users: [params[:user_id]] }} if params[:user_id]
    ...
  end
end
```

Where location_users is mapped as an array during the indexing by tire.

```
def to_indexed_json
  to_json methods: [:location_users]
end

def location_users
  location.users.map(&:id) if location
end
```

(I don't want a user searching someone else's accounting data)

Using the river, I wrote some sql to get the data and associated table columns from MySQL. The only way I could get a list of location_users was by doing something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, l.location_name, GROUP_CONCAT(lu.id) as location_users FROM accounts...
```

That gave me a location_users field with comma separated values. But obviously not an array.

Now when I search, I get zero results because the filter's looking for an array and it's just a list that's returned.

Is there a way I can either index this field as an array? Or is there a way to alter the filter so it works again?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the SQl like this:

```
SELECT a.*, l.location_name, GROUP_CONCAT(lu.id) as `location_users[]` FROM accounts...
```

When a field name end with '[]', Elasticsearch river JDBC plugin will transform the value to array by splitting the value (using comma as separator) and store it. 
So field data **'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'** will become **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]** when indexing

Comment: Wasn't aware of this. Will test later.